# Sorted Map with not well-defined Comparators

Tags: java

I'm searching for a Map implementation which can be sorted based on its keys and a Comparator.

I know that `TreeMap` is the way to go, but I have a huge problem: The comparator is not well defined (which I know is an mistake, but I can not fix it currently) in terms that it returns 0 even for keys which are not equal (in terms of equals() method).

The TreeMap implementation assumes that objects are equal (and therefore overwrites the values) if the comparator returns 0 and does not take the hashCode or the equals method of the object into consideration. This is documented and in most cases the desired behaviour. You can check that the implementation is based on the comparator by looking in the TreeMap.put() method, which contains the following snipset:

```
        do {
            parent = t;
            cmp = cpr.compare(key, t.key);
            if (cmp < 0)
                t = t.left;
            else if (cmp > 0)
                t = t.right;
            else
                return t.setValue(value);
        } while (t != null);
```

This code walks the tree and if it finds a node in the tree which is equal (using the comparator `cpr`) to the one which should be inserted (`key`), the value is overwritten.

But: I'm searching for an implementation of the Map interface which is sorted based on a Comparator but does not use it for detecting which are equal.

Comment: are you putting into the map some your class or java classes?

Comment: For both keys and values: My classes

Comment: as far as I know, map is implemented by Sets, and whether object is in set, is determined by hashCode() of the object itself, not by equals from comparator, so why TreeMap is not working?

Comment: See my edit above, it is not based on a `Set`.

Comment: What is the usage pattern? Are you creating the map first and then iterating over it lots of times with no further modifications, or do you need to keep updating it as you go along?

Comment: @Miloš `Map` (the interface) is not implemented in any particular way, it just describes functionality.  The `java.util.TreeMap` implementation, on the other hand, *does* use Comparators to determine object equality, as described by its Javadocs.  theomega is right that he cannot use TreeMaps if his comparator is not consistent with equals.

Comment: yes, you're right, just checked it in javadoc, and I implicitly though of TreeMap when I was talking about map :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt you will find a Map that does that, since it goes against the recommendation of the Comparator interface.

> The ordering imposed by a comparator c on a set of elements S is said
>   to be **consistent with equals** if and only if c.compare(e1, e2)==0 has
>   the same boolean value as e1.equals(e2) for every e1 and e2 in S.
>
> Caution should be exercised when using a comparator capable of
>   imposing an ordering inconsistent with equals to order a sorted set
>   (or sorted map). Suppose a sorted set (or sorted map) with an explicit
>   comparator c is used with elements (or keys) drawn from a set S. If
>   the ordering imposed by c on S is inconsistent with equals, the sorted
>   set (or sorted map) will behave "**strangely**." In particular the sorted
>   set (or sorted map) will violate the general contract for set (or
>   map), which is defined in terms of equals.

You can always decorate the comparator with your own comparator like so `new MyComparator(faultyComparator);`

When you deletegate the calls to the  faulty comparator, check its return value. If it is 0, make sure the `equals()` contract of the objects agree. If they don't, rectify the return value. An even better solution is to rewrite the comparator correctly and  use a TreeMap, if that option is open.

Comment: The solution to wrap the comparator is good, I hoped to not be forced to use it...

Comment: The difficult part with wrapping the comparator is ensuring that `a < b => b > a` _consistently_ for all pairs, even when the original comparator thinks they're equal. You can't simply have it always return -1 or +1 as that will break the TreeMap.

Comment: Unfortunately your options are limited if you cannot modify the `Comparator` itself. What @IanRoberts is alluding to is also correct. My decorator solution assumes that you have enough information to make an informed decision on a > b or vice-versa. Arbitrarily returning -1 / +1 wont work.

Comment: How about using the hash code in case the wrapped comparator returns 0?

Answer (score 0):

TreeMap should be alright in your case. But, it sounds like you are not using Strings or Wrapper class objects as keys. If you use your own class object as key, you must implement hashcode() and equals() method.

Comment: My equals and hashcode implementations are correct, the problem is the incorrect Comparator, which I (as explained above) can not change.

Comment: Why do you need to worry about Comparator? Are you using any Comparator in your own program along with TreeMap?

Comment: Yes, I'm using a custom comparator which is implemented incorrectly.

Comment: If you class extends Comparable then you can compare your objects using compareTo() method. Now, if your equals method implementation contains to check two objects using compareTo(), shouldn't this work? But you need to be careful as there are three different outputs from compareTo (-1,0, +1)

Answer (score 0):

Simply implement a Comparator that never returns 0 and use regular TreeMap.

Answer (score 0):

It'd be rather more housekeeping but it sounds to me like you need some sort of two level structure, a `TreeMap<K, LinkedHashMap<K, V>>` where the outer map is based on your "faulty" comparator and its values are normal equals-aware maps (whose keys will all be equal according to the comparator, but different according to hashCode and equals).